# How to simulate a sample with density $f^p / \int f^p$?

Tags: simulation, density-function, sample

Given a density $f$ (or given a $n$-sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ with density $f$), is there a way to create a $n'$-sample $X_{p,1}, \ldots, X_{p,n'}$ with density $f^p / \int f^p$, where $p \in \mathbb{N}, p > 1$?

Comment: How does this question arise?  Are you aware that when $f$ is a density that $C f^p$ need not be a density for any such $p \gt 1$?  (Consider $f(x) = 1/(2\sqrt{x})$ for $0\le x\le 1$.)